# C# plugin framework

Tags: c#, plugins, interface, frameworks

I have a plugin framework implemented in C#, with the plugin interface written in C# and compiled in a DLL. Is there a way I can write a plugin for that framework in a .NET language other than C#? Thanks for your time!

Comment: What happens when you create a project in another language and reference the DLL in that project?

Answer (score 2):

The DLL is compiled to [MSIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), not C#. Any language that uses the .Net framework will be able to reference and build off of the DLL, as it's not language dependant. You will be able to inherit your base plugin class from any .Net based language by default.

Comment: OK, that answers my main question, thanks! Do you have any concrete example of a C# interface implemented in VB? How should I refer to my C# interface in my VB class? Are there any .NET conventions?

Comment: It's just like how you would do it any other way from C#. You just reference the dll, add the namespace, then use it just like the class was written in VB, the compiler will handle the rest.

Comment: OK, perfect! Thanks again.